# Circuit Simulator for iPad

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, ipad

What is the best electronics circuit simulator app for iPad where I can draw a circuit and monitor its behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few, if you are a Spice fanatic then I'd give this one a try first:

[Spicy Schematics Free](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/spicy-schematics-free/id480361067?mt=8) is a trial version of the full iPad app, [Spicy Schematics](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/spicy-schematics/id434107624?mt=8)

[Circuit Lab HD](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/circuit-lab-hd/id401263775?mt=8) and [DCircuit Lab HD](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/dcircuit-lab-hd/id392966166?mt=8) are two fully featured node analysis simulators, the first is an analog simulator in the Spice mould, the second purely for Digital gate and logic combinatory analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Although I personally haven't used it the [iCircuit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icircuit/id383359044?mt=8) app seems to provide everything you are looking for.

Comment: I have iCircuit, and for what it is, it's excellent. I's certainly not a full-blown SPICE replacement, but for sketching out simple ideas, it works very well.

Comment: If you want to get an idea of what it can (and cannot) do, it's based/inspired heavily on the Falstac Circuit Simulator Java Applet, which is free online here: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ The two pieces of software are very similar in look and in the simulated devices (iCircuit has a slightly better schematic editor, though, ans it had to be refined to make it work with the touch controls).

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: *I am affiliated with the company that makes and sells this app*.

The paid version of our iPad app named Spicy Schematics would be best as it has more features of the [original SPICE circuit emulation software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE), but you can also try the [free version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spicy-schematics/id434107624?mt=8) if you are not ready to buy.

Lastly, we also have [PC, Mac and Web app versions of the tool](http://ischematics.com), so that may sway your decision to use our iPad version. We hope to have syncing approved by Apple so that your iPad and web simulations can be synchronized, but this feature is not reviewed yet.